# Front Door + App Service with built-in authentication not working

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

I'm trying to use **App Service** with standard **App Registration** built-in authentication behind a **Front Door** with no success.

My setup is:

1. An App Service "myapp.azurewebsites.com" with built-in authentication.
2. App Registration "app-auth" as auth provider.
3. I have "app-auth" configured in my App Service for automatic authentication via Provider.
4. Front Door "frontdoor.example.com" forwards requests to my App Service.

My App Registration "app-auth" has a redirect URL assigned the Front Door public name example "frontdoor.example.com".

Problems I'm having:

- App Service keeps sending it's own name "myapp.azurewebsites.com" as `request_uri` query string login in to Azure Active Directory. It must send the Front Door URL.
  [image]
- Setting up "frontdoor.example.com" `host` header in Front Door fails, as it [requires it to match the App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-backend-pool#backend-host-header) name.
  [image]

Am I missing some configuration? Or, do I need to use custom authentication when behind a Front Door?

Comment: Could you share your C# code for authentication please ? you need to override the redirect_uri. Also which net version / framewrok are you using ?

Comment: @Thomas with built-in authentication code there is no need for code. That is the purpose of that feature in App Services, no-code authentication. It works perfectly on App Services directly, problem is behind a load balancer, on which I can't find a way to configure the redirect_uri.

Comment: @EvandroPomatti did you solved this issue?

Comment: @SanjeeviSubramani I think we ended up removing app service built-in auth as a workaround. If you identify the solution please post an answer here.

Comment: @EvandroPomatti i used custom Azure AD authentication instead of inbuilt and achieved it - here is a article for it :
https://lkgforit.com/how-to-setup-azure-front-door-for-aspnet-mvc-webapp-hosted-in-azure-app-service-with-azure-ad-authentication

Comment: Did you find a solution? I used this article https://vincentlauzon.com/2019/07/17/azure-app-service-authentication-with-azure-front-door/ but im stuck in endless 302 redirects.

Comment: @Tobi not sure, it's been a while. If I get the opportunity to set up that again I'll update it here.

Comment: Thanks. I posted a complete solution here.

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work, you need to add the custom domain (frontdoor.example.com) also to your app service. This can be done using DNS verification.

- Go to your App Service
- Go to Custom Domains
- Copy the Custom Domain Verification ID
- Add a new DNS TXT record with the copied value: `TXT asuid.frontdoor.example.com. <verification id>`

[image: App Service Custom Domain Verification ID (image)]

To ensure Front Door forwards the request Host Header, the `Origin host header` field in your Origin configuration must be blank.

Then, when Front Door forwards the request Host Header (`Host: frontdoor.example.com`) the App Service will recognize it and the Azure AD authentication will use it as for redirection.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have misconfigured the redirect URI in your APP service registration in Azure AD, that is where you specify the redirect_URI, it has nothing to do with the app service or the front door itself.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inbuilt Azure AD authentication in Azure App service i used custom Azure AD authentication in my dotnet core app by following this stackoverflow answer:

[Authentication with Azure AD redirect_uri is incorrect using FrontDoor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61733729/authentication-with-azure-ad-redirect-uri-is-incorrect-using-frontdoor)

I wrote an article on the same refer it here:

https://www.lkgforit.com/2022/10/how-to-setup-azure-front-door-for.html

Answer (score 0):

For me worked changing the auth settings for the Azure Web app. First:

```
"httpSettings": {
  "forwardProxy": {
    "convention": "Standard"
```

By default, I had there "NoProxy".

Second:

```
"validation": {
      "defaultAuthorizationPolicy": {
        "allowedPrincipals": {}
      },
      "allowedAudiences": ["https://<my-url>.z01.azurefd.net",
                    "https://<my-app-url>.azurewebsites.net"]
```

I had to add this "allowedAudiences" with urls to frontdoor and original url of the web app.
And the last:

```
"login": {
  "allowedExternalRedirectUrls": [
```

I had to add

```
https://<my-url>.z01.azurefd.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
```

Then it started to work. You can download the file by executing:

```
az rest --uri /subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourceGroups/<resource group name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<site name>/config/authsettingsV2?api-version=2020-09-01 --method get
```

Update it accordingly and the upload by executing

```
az rest --uri /subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourceGroups/<resource group name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<site name>/config/authsettingsV2?api-version=2020-09-01 --method put --body @auth.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an article describing a solution.
https://vincentlauzon.com/2019/07/17/azure-app-service-authentication-with-azure-front-door/

I used self signed ssl certificates. That works fine. Don't forget the "extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth"

```bash
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -days 1096 -key key.pem -out my.cer -addext "extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth" 
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey key.pem -in ./my.cer -out certificate.pfx
```

I had to adapt the solution by adding to the webapp as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization
You have to do it via the command line. You cannot set it in the portal.

```json
"httpSettings": {
  "forwardProxy": {
    "convention": "Standard"
  }
}
```

In my front door route mapsI routed the traffic to a subfolder of the web app, this I had to remove as the requests ended in an endless 302 Loop.
[image]
Now it works.

[image]